# Delete a repeating pattern in a string using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a JavaScript file with an array of data.

```
info = [ {
Date = "YR-MM-DDT00:00:10"
}, ....
```

What I'm trying to do is remove T and on in the Date field.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import re
with open ("info.js","r") as myFile:
    data= myFile.read();
    data= re.sub('\0-9T,'',data);
```

Desired output for each Date field in the array:

```
Date = "YR-MM-DD"
```

Comment: Questions that ask for a [regex to match X](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed) are off-topic. Please use any of the many, many existing regex validation tools online for this purpose.

Comment: That doesn't look like it works. What do you expect the regex to do? Give an example of input and output, the most basic thing which should match (nevermind timestamps, just anything simple). Nevermind files for that matter, just a string.

Comment: Every time I encounter a number followed by a T, i'd like to remove everything in that line from that point on.

Comment: Is it possible to have a T that comes too early?  How important is it to check for a number?

Comment: A number will always come before a T, but T's will appear in names of other data fields, but never a number followed by a T. So 0-9 T is the pattern I'd like to find and remove what follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the T and the characters that come after it, This works for a single timestamp:

```
import re

print(re.sub('T.*$', '', 'YR-MM-DDT00:00:10'))
```

Or if you have text containing a bunch of timestamps, match the closing double quote as well, and replace with a double quote:

```
import re

text = """
  info = [ {
    Date = "YR-MM-DDT00:00:10",
    Date = "YR-MM-DDT01:02:03",
    Date = "YR-MM-DDT11:22:33"
  }
"""

new_text = re.sub('T.*"', '"', text)
print(new_text)
```